# Setting the space between page header and text block

Tags: header-footer

I work with documentclass report and use `fancyhdr` package for chapters in this way:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\nouppercase\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
}
```

I would like to change space between the line and the following text. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `fancyhdr` isn't involved: the relevant parameter is `\headsep`. Perhaps using `geometry` is the best strategy.

Comment: You have two redefinitions of `\chaptermark` and two competing settings of `\headrulewidth`. Please consider eliminating the deadwood code.

Comment: @Mico The second definition of `\headrulewidth` is correct, being in `\fancypagestyle`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I hadn't noticed this feature.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As @egreg pointed out in the comments, you have to adjust the length `headsep`. This can be done in the following ways:

1. Use the command `\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}` where you can put the relevant value of length.
2. Use the package `geometry` as `\usepackage[margin=1in,headsep=.2in]{geometry}`.

As pointed in the comment by @Mico in the comments, you have defined `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}.....`two times.  Please correct them.

Comment: The second `\fancyhead{}` is correct, being in `\fancypagestyle`. The same for `\headrulewidth`.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry overlooked it. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions are working. I'm just a little bit confused now... Should I delete one of the renewcommands for \chaptermark and \headrulewidth or not?

Comment: @Jane: headrulewidth is ok. Everything depends on your class and whether two side/what do you want as header. I feel that the first three `renewcommand`s -- `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}`
 can be safely removed if you wish.

Comment: I want to mantain both top and bottom margin while increasing the space between page header and text block, and finally have that same space between the text and footer, too. Increasing `headsep` and `footskip` by the same amount AND then decreasing `textheight` accordingly doesn't do the trick, as there isn't an equivalent definition of `headsep` for the footer. Any help?