# Header in Middle of Top Rule

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry, header

I am trying to create a header so that it looks like the image below such that the header is not right on top of the first line

[image]

However, I played with the dimensions on this MWE and can't seem to get it to work. I am wondering if I may be able to get some insight on how to do this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage} %full page typesetting
\usepackage{setspace} %allows for non-singlespacing
\usepackage{graphicx} %graphics capabilities
\usepackage{latexsym} %extra symbols
\usepackage{rotating} %rotation for figures
\usepackage{longtable} %tables that fill more than a single page
\usepackage{hyperref} %hypertext links in the document
\usepackage{natbib} %better bibliographies
\usepackage{authblk} %author and affiliation in opening


%Put name and page number on subsequent pages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\rhead{\emph{Some Header}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\newcommand\e{\emph}
\newcommand\tb{\textbf}
\newcommand\un{\underline}
\newcommand\txt{\texttt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the value of `\headsep` uwing `\setlength{\headsep}{<length of your choice>}` in your preamble, as also explained here: [Setting the space between page header and text block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56539/134144)

Comment: Is your concern here that the header element should be centred on the page (not right) or that it should be at a different position *vertically* (as in, not at the top)?

Comment: This is caused by the `fullspace` package. By default it sets the `\headsep` to 0, because it thinks you have no header (default is `plain` page style, which doesn't have a header. By using `\usepackage[headings]{fullpage}` you specify that it does have headers. It would by itself use the page style `headings`, but you overwrite that with `fancyhdr`.