# Multi line header does not play well with geometry headsep parameter

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, geometry, rules

I would like to use the `geometry` package alongside `fancyhdr`. To control the distance between header and main text in my `article` documentclass, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56539/setting-the-space-between-page-header-and-text-block) recommends use of the `headsep` parameter:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[includehead, headsep=5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{A header}%\\a new line in the header}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
  \section*{Education}

\end{document}
```

This seems to work fine, and modifying the `headsep` indeed modifies the distance between the header and the section title.
[image]
However, it so happens that my header is multi-line. as soon as I uncomment line 9 as follows:

`\fancyhead[C]{A header\\a new line in the header}`

The section title clashes with the header, which I do not want.
[image]
How can I get `headsep` to remain aware that my header is now multi line?

Comment: Perhaps you should also modify `headheight`?

Comment: It's just a bit confusing to me why that would be necessary, since according to the `geometry` package docs "If `includehead` is set to `true`, `headheight` and `headsep` are considered as a part of `height`". So I would argue that geometry should calculate the appropriate `headheight` for me ?

Comment: Oh! sorry, I skimmed this  point. What was your new value of headsep?

Comment: I just kept the same value of `headsep`. But do you think that should matter anyway? I would have expected `geometry` to calculate the correct `headheight` such that no matter what `headsep` I pick it would always work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to. I've just tested, and setting headsep to `4ex` yields a correct result. There are warnings as to headheight being too small, and advising to make it at least 25.52pt.

Comment: so `includehead` only works for single line headers? That seems a little... limiting?

Comment: There is a default headheight, which is set to 12pt.

Comment: Oh... so `geometry` doesn't dynamically calculate the `headheight` based on the header generated by `fancyhdr`. I see what you're saying. In that case, can I redefine the default `headheight` in `geometry` based on my real `fancyhdr` header instead of hardcoding it like that? In other words, is the real `headheight` value stored in a variable somewhere and can I pass that to `geometry`?

Comment: It's a key; you can change its value through the optional arguments for geometry in your preamble, or specify it with `geometry{headheight=…}`. I think it's better to specify it in the ex unit, so if you decide to modify the font size of your document, you shoudn't have any modification to  do for headheight.

Comment: or set up fancyhdr first including then set up geometry after you have set up the heading, if you increase the size of the content after setting up the page the output you show isn't that surprising

Comment: A future version of `fancyhdr` will have a (limited) facility to automatically calculate `\headheight` and pass it to `geometry`. I have it working in my private development copy. For now use `\usepackage[includehead, headsep=30pt,headheight=26pt]{geometry}` or similar. For the value needed for `headheight`` see your `.log` file.

Comment: IIRC, fancyhdr **changes** \headheight in the middle of the document.  Geometry runs in the preamble and no long has any control.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the OP's code, I just augmented the `\headheight` and decremented the `\topmargin` by equal amounts.  Then, the header behaves as I presume the OP would desire.

MWEs below show single-line and double-line header.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[includehead, headsep=5pt]{geometry}
\headheight=\dimexpr\headheight+15pt 
\topmargin=\dimexpr\topmargin-15pt 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{A header a new line in the header}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
  \section*{Education}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[includehead, headsep=5pt]{geometry}
\headheight=\dimexpr\headheight+15pt 
\topmargin=\dimexpr\topmargin-15pt 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{A header\\ a new line in the header}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
  \section*{Education}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get a nice layout of a page

[image: z]

use the `layout` package to understand the various dimensions involved in designing a page and their relationships.

To have two lines in the header space you need to set `headheight=25pt` (5) or more, if plan to add more lines or a figure. Then to separate the header from the text area set `headsep=20pt` (6) or similar. Finally to allocate enough space from the top of the physical page to the top of the text area set the `top= 1in` or more.

[image: x]
.
[image: y]
[image: y]

The  headheight, the headsep, and others
are fixed spaces reserved for your use. They are not aware of overflows nor they collapse in the absence of content.

There’s more than one way to skin a cat.
If you overspecify `geometry` will complain.

The log file is also instructive.

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: luatex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: luatex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: includehead 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(89.62709pt, 418.25368pt, 89.6271pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(60.0pt, 683.6402pt, 101.40665pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=418.25368pt
* \textheight=633.6402pt
* \oddsidemargin=17.3571pt
* \evensidemargin=17.3571pt
* \topmargin=-12.26999pt
* \headheight=25.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=50.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
```

This is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ headheight=25pt, headsep=25pt, top = 60pt, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{layout}% added<<<<<

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{A header \\ a new line in the header}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
    \layout% added<<<<<
    \section*{Education}    
\end{document}
```